# Slicing array in regions - Python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I have to "divide" an `n x m` array in regions using a mask input.

For example, suppose I have a `20 x 20` array. My mask is the following (`5 x 5`) -- always:

[image]

where the numbers represent the regions in which the cells take part. This mask is not an input, that is just an `ndarray`. This mask just represent how I should slice my `20 x 20` at every `5 x 5` neighborhood.

For example, the first region comprehend the indices:

> (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)

For each `5 x 5`neighborhood of my `20 x 20` array, I should return the values that are in each of the `8`regions.

I know how to do that with a "standard code", but I wondering if there is a *Pythonic* way of do that, possible with a concise code.

As a code example, I could do something like:

```
def slice_in_regions(data, x_dim, y_dim):
    for x in xrange(0, x_dim, 5):
        for y in xrange(0, y_dim, 5):
            neighbors = data[x:x+4, y:y+4]
            region1 = [neighbors[0,0], neighbors[1,0], neighbors[1,1], neighbors[2,0], neighbors[2,1], neighbors[2,2]]
            # region2, region3...
```

However, that doesn't seem to be a good way to do that. Moreover, I'm counting on that my data will dimension be multiple of `5`.

Thank you.

Comment: without more information about input and output of your program it's hard to help you. Could you provide an exemple : input + mask and expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could probably just resize your mask, e.g. if you're already using `numpy`,

```
mask = mask.repeat(4, axis=0).repeat(4, axis=1)
# Then you apply the mask using 
values = data[mask]
```

Otherwise,

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.repeat(mask, 4, axis=0).repeat(4, axis=1)
# Then you apply the mask using 
values = np.array(data)[mask]
```

**Individual regions**

If you need to access each region individually, you could 
precede the previous by using a labelled mask; as the labels will be 
grown into labelled regions you can then use, e.g.

```
values = [ data[mask==l] for l in range(1, mask.max()+1)]
```

Here values will be a list of arrays where each item corresponds to a labelled region in `mask`.

**Generating the labelled mask**

For completeness, to get from a binary mask to a labelled mask where every on pixel has it's own label you could use `scipy.ndimage.label`

```
mask = ndimage.label(mask, [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])
```

or if using a region labelling function is overkill, you can achieve a similar result using

```
mask[mask] = range(1,mask.sum()+1)
```

Comment: Pretty interesting, @jmetz. Didn't know about that! Just one question, it is possible to use this approach in a mask in witch some values should be in different regions? For example, in the image that I posted, some of them have the label 1/2, which means that this position should be returned to region 1 and 2.

Comment: @pceccon - I'd use additional labels for that case and then add the values from the additional labels into the target regions afterwards.

Comment: This means that you would have multiples "label masks", one for each region, for example?

Comment: @pceccon - that would be inefficient; I meant that just as you have regions in your image such as "1/2", this would be translated into a new label e.g. 9. Then once the values are extracted, use a mapping to append values in 9 to 1 and 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes. (: Thank you. I'll try to understand better about `ndimage.label`. A read the documentation but didn't get it well yet. Thank you.